# Relationships between the singular values and eigenvalues of an asymmetric matrix A

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition, svd

As we know, if A is a real and symmetric matrix, the SVD decomposition is just the eigendecomposition, and the singular values and singular vectors are just eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

For the case that A is real but not symmetric, what are the relationships between the singular values and eigenvalues of A?

Thanks!